# How to design Entity so that it stores predefined field

Tags: java, hibernate

Let us suppose that I successfully created a DB table and corresponding java Entity. This entity represents position a worker may take. As the Primary Key it uses incremented id number instead of business key:

```
@Entity
public class Position {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String positionName;

private String description;

// getters and setters

}
```

Let us suppose the company has three positions:

```
id: 1 positionName: "Teacher"  description: "To be edited"
id: 2 positionName: "Janitor"  description: "To be edited"
id: 3 positionName: "Chairman" description: "To be edited"
```

Now we have a Employee entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;

private String surname;

// HERE THE PROBLEMATIC RELATION
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name = "positionId") 
public Position position;

// getters and setters

}
```

As you may suppose this design of Employee entity causes problems.
When using Spring for POSTing in JSON format for new Employee(s) I send following data to persist a new Employee Ellen Johansson with Teacher position:

```
 {
   "name" : "Ellen",
   "surname" : "Johansson",
   "position" : {
    "id" : 1
    }
 }
```

As you may guess this POSTing overrides existing Position for id = 1 and as both positionName and positionDesription are null I end up with edited Position table as such:

```
id: 1 positionName: null  description: null
id: 2 positionName: "Janitor"  description: "To be edited"
id: 3 positionName: "Chairman" description: "To be edited"
```

How do I design my Employee Position relation so that:

It is enough to state position id when persisting new Employee but this does not override existing rows in predefined Position table and does not add a new row if row described by position id does not exist in Position table?

*I guess OneToOne relation is making everything collapse and I should use somewhat @Embedded relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it probably should be a ManyToOne: there are usually several employees with the same job.

Second: you're mixing three completely different aspects:

1. how your persistence model should be designed,
2. how your HTTP API should be designed,
3. How to assign an employee to an existing position

Regarding the first point, except for the OneToOne which should be a ManyToOne, you're covered.

Regarding the second point: you don't want to accept an Employee with a Position in your API. You want to accept the data that is needed to create an Employee (which could be equal, less, or more than what an `Employee` entity contains), and what is needed to know what its position should be, i.e. the ID of the position. So don't use a persistent JPA entity to represent the input of your API. Use a dedicated `EmployeeCreationCommand` class containing exactly what the client should send (nothing more, nothing less), in order to create an employee: name, surname, position ID.

Regarding the third point: now that you receive the information about the employee to create, incuding the ID of its position, you need to

- get the `Position` entity identified by the received position ID
- create an Employee instance populated with the information received in the command, and linked to the Position instance you got in the previous step
- persist this employee

Comment: Yes I thought there is a way to avoid fetching Position entity that corresponds to positionid given in an Employee (possibly EmployeeCreationCommand) instance. I really do not like DTOs. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use hibernate you would normally fetch the position first and then set it to the employee. You maybe also want to distinguish between your entity and api model because it seems like you dont really want to be able to set the other position fields in your request.